# How to search wikipedia and get input or info in C++?

Tags: c++

I want my program to search wikipedia and get the info it searches for and put it into a large string and output into a file. How can I do that in C++? Any info please tell? need more anwsers please

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to consider using, say, python instead? It's pretty easy to learn, and getting a web page is ridiculously easy.

Comment: Hell yeah, and you can always link back into C++ with Boost.Python ;)

Answer (score 6):

Use [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) with the query URL

```
wget --output-document=result.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=jon+skeet&go=Go
```

This searches for **jon skeet** and stores the result in **result.html**

To use it from C++ you can e.g. use the system() call to execute wget in a seperate process.

Comment: And, if you don't like that route, you can grab the free source code to wget to inform your own solution.

Comment: umm can you get a source code or example and post somewhere and post on this website again please

Comment: And now I know that Jon Skeet was a contributing author of "Groovy in Action". Interesting.

Comment: What, you mean make the community do the work for you? That's nasty ;-)

Comment: LOL sorry but a little bit ive been searching this on and off but nothing and  i think yall can do it

Comment: Now this is sounding more like a homework assignment, especially since you can't figure out how to browse the wget source repository.

Answer (score 4):

[libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) is pretty popular. I don't know that the interface is especially object-oriented, but it's certainly usable from C++.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of client APIs for MediaWiki (the wiki engine that powers Wikipedia). [Here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_Code)'s a listing. They provide the ability to create/delete/edit/search articles. Nothing in straight C++ but it still may be useful.

[DotNetWikiBot](http://dotnetwikibot.sourceforge.net/) was quite useful on one project that I had...

Comment: I just hate downvotes for an answer without an explanation of why it's not helpful...